# How do I automate an app that is not mine using appium on an ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, automation, appium

So, I have an iPhone actual device here. And I have an app on there, say Tinder.

Let's say I want to write some automation that would automate some actions within Tinder.

I cannot find any documentation online, on how to setup a way to automate, on my real device using appium to open the Tinder app and swipe left or right.

I was told it has something to do with installing appium server directly on the iPhone and have your code connect into the appium server on the phone to automate that way. But again, can't find any documentation on this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
I would like to write the automation that interfaces with appium using ruby.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Appium to automate a 3rd party ios app on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090109/how-to-use-appium-to-automate-a-3rd-party-ios-app-on-real-device)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. If you want to automate on iOS, you need the simulator build or source code.
However, on Android, as long as you have .apk you can automate it :)

Sources: http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#appium-on-real-ios-devices
http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#ios-support

Comment: Yes I understand for ios it's only a simulator instead of an emulator like in android where it emulates the ARM chip. the ipa file like the apk file is compiled for the ARM chip. therefore, in order to run the ipa, I must run it on a real ios device. I just didn't know if appium can hook into that real device to automate that. And I'm looking for docs or how to's if it can. No one has seemed to produce any out there for this.

Comment: If you have all of the requirements to do so (Apple Developer ID, iPad/iPhone, signed, .ipa or source, A Mac with Xcode and Xcode Command Line developer tools), it's just a matter of having the correct desired capabilities.  You'll need: app, platformname, platformversion, devicename, and udid.