# How to use Appium to automate a 3rd party ios app on real device

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

I'm trying to automate a 3rd party `ios` app (YouTube, for example) on a real `iPhone` using `Appium`. I haven't been able to find a single guide/tutorial to achieve this, but from the information I gathered, it seems to involve the following steps:

1. Extract the pre-installed app and decrypted it (using a tool such as [Clutch](https://github.com/KJCracks/Clutch))
2. Resign it with my development cert

I know I omitted lots of details in each step, but my question is, has anyone done this successfully and can confirm this is actually achievable? Or is there any other less involved ways to automate a 3rd party ios app using `Appium`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Automate app already installed on the device, you can use `bundleId` capability and provide the bundle id of the installed app.

You can learn more about how to get the `bundleId` for an installed app, [here](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/202916391-Find-Your-App-s-Bundle-ID).

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to extract the pre-installed app and install/automate it on a different device using Appium, is the resign/repack steps the only way to do it?

Comment: If my answer helped you then can you accept it? For pre installed part you said, I haven't tried that. Let me know how you did that if you are successful.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Try this link: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/faq/finding-the-app-bundle-id/