# How do I automate iOS apps that I don't own on real iOS devices using Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

First, I know there is already a similar question asked ([How do I automate an app that is not mine using appium on an ios device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635966/how-do-i-automate-an-app-that-is-not-mine-using-appium-on-an-ios-device)), but it's been a while and I am hoping to find out if there is any new information or technology to achieve it.

So, the goal is to automate `iOS` apps that I do not own (e.g. `GoogleMaps`) using `Appium` on real `iOS` devices. So far the closest way I can achieve that is by using a tool like iMazing to download an app installed from App Store into an `IPA` file, and then have Appium to automate it using the "App" capability. But this only works if the `AppleId` in the `IPA` file's itunesmetadata.plist matches the device used for the test. So if I were to run the automation on a different device I have to unzip the `IPA` file, modify the `AppleId` to match the device, and then archive it back.

**QUESTIONS**

1. I'm trying to find a way for not having to do this, a way to extract/download an app I don't own and produces an app file that Appium can just automate.
2. Or, even a wholly different (and better) way to achieve my goal - to automate `iOS` apps that I do not own (e.g. `GoogleMaps`) using `Appium` on real `iOS` devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Appium to automate a 3rd party ios app on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090109/how-to-use-appium-to-automate-a-3rd-party-ios-app-on-real-device)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, its still not possible.

You can interact with apps, you don't own in very limited way (if it is running on simulator, than only with pre-installed apps + yours, installed from XCode).

In case of real device - as you said - you can install it via `IPA` file and try to automate it after this by modifying the `plist`. This could be (in theory) done by some script, that you would provide the package, it would disassemble it, change the line in `plist` file and assemble it back together for all devices, you need.
There is no other way to do this (afaik). That should answer your `1/`.

As to the point `2/`. Why would you want to automate testing for apps, you don't own? Yes, you may have `webview` or `Google Maps` plugin, you want to test, but you can test that without installing the full app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run app which is already installed on the device and is not owned by you, you can use `bundleId` capability with bundle id of the app to automate.

You can learn more about how to get the `bundleId` for an installed app, [here](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/202916391-Find-Your-App-s-Bundle-ID).